# How can I solve this issue in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento2

I installed the pearl theme 2.3x after installed and did the configuration after that I got this error I can't understand the issue please help me to fix this issue.

I using **Cloudflare** server and the os is **Debian gnu Linux 9** and **Magento version is 2.3**

**Issue**

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
> (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'font':
> This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link,
> meta, script, remove, attribute ). Line: 1285
>
> Element 'font': This element is not expected. Expected is one of (
> title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ). Line: 1293
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):
> Element 'font': This element is not expected. Expected is one of (
> title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ). Line: 1285
>
> Element 'font': This element is not expected. Expected is one of (
> title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ). Line: 1293
>
> ```
> #1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('createObject('Magento\Framewor...',
> array('create('Magento\Framewor...',
> array('xml' => '
> '/mnt/data/home/2...', 'validationState' =>
> &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000003e5a6782000000001b0cec1a#))
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
> #4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewor...',
> array('xml' => '
> '/mnt/data/home/2...', 'validationState' =>
> &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000003e5a6782000000001b0cec1a#))
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php:43]
> #5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(array('xml' => ' '/mnt/data/home/2...',
> 'validationState' =>
> &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000003e5a6782000000001b0cec1a#))
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php:141]
> #6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend_...',
> '\n   load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:86]
> #9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:63]
> #10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:253]
> #11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:875]
> #12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_hea...') called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php:171]
> #13 Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(&Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000003e5a65a2000000001b0cec1a#,
> 'vaanyard-applied...') called at
> [vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php:74]
> #14 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
> #15 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#)
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
> #16 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
> array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#))
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
> #17 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#)
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
> #18 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
> array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#),
> array(array('designLoader', 'customerNotifica...',
> 'catalog_app_acti...', 'tax-app-action-d...', 'weee-app-action-...',
> 'storeCheck', 'contextPlugin', 'customer-app-act...'))) called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:26]
> #19 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#)
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
> #20 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#,
> &Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000003e5a65a2000000001b0cec1a#)
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
> #21 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#)
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
> #22 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
> array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#))
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
> #23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
> #24 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000003e5a662e000000001b0cec1a#,
> &Closure#000000003e5a67cd000000001b0cec1a#,
> &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#)
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
> #25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
> #26 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#000000003e5a662e000000001b0cec1a#,
> &Closure#000000003e5a67cd000000001b0cec1a#,
> &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#)
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
> #27 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#)
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
> #28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
> array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#),
> NULL) called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
> #29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003e5a66a0000000001b0cec1a#)
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]
> #30 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
> #31 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000003e5a665f000000001b0cec1a#)
> called at [1010.php:39]
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like in one of your layout xml file header blocks, an illegal 'font' element is there.

Check your layout xml files. Specially header_default_block.xml files and basically all xml files for something like '<font'. If it is there, then remove it and see. May be you have to regenerate static content again.

Comment: Thank you for your help
weltpixel_design_elements_fonts_core.xml
weltpixel_design_elements_fonts_extended.xml